# Linkedin API returns unknown field in resource person

Tags: php, linkedin-api

so I'm fairly new with working in Linkedin API, I'm trying to fetch details of **r_basicprofile**, but I get this error.

```
Unknown field {position} in resource {Person}
```

Here's my code :-

```
$xml_response = $linkedin->getProfile("~:(id,email-address,num-connections,industry,position)");
```

What wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column position should be [positions](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile)

Try

```
$xml_response = $linkedin->getProfile("~:(id,email-address,num-connections,industry,positions)");
```

That will return a list of [position objects](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/positions)